# Knitr/Sweave Format Code Output w/ Leading Characters

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Using knitr/sweave, I need to format the R code output that gets echoed, according to editorial journal requirements.

For example, the following chunk

```
<<example,echo=TRUE>>=
library(plyr)
@
```

Is formatted as follows:

```
> library(plyr)
```

However, I would like it to be formatted like this:

```
R> library(plyr)
```

How can I modify the leading chevron?

---

**Sweave format is being used via the following chunk:**

```
%Read the Script into File
<<setup,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>=
    render_sweave()
@
```

---

**I am using the following `sweave.sty`**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{Sweave}{}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{Sweave@gin}
\setboolean{Sweave@gin}{true}
\newboolean{Sweave@ae}
\setboolean{Sweave@ae}{true}

\DeclareOption{nogin}{\setboolean{Sweave@gin}{false}}
\DeclareOption{noae}{\setboolean{Sweave@ae}{false}}
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{graphicx,fancyvrb,textcomp}
%% inspired by an earlier version of upquote.sty
\begingroup
\catcode`'=\active \catcode``=\active
\g@addto@macro\@noligs{\let`\textasciigrave \let'\textquotesingle}
\endgroup

\ifthenelse{\boolean{Sweave@gin}}{\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}}{}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{Sweave@ae}}{%
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage{ae}
}{}%

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}

\ifdefined\Schunk%
  \message{\string Environment Schunk is already defined, stay with former definition}%
\else
  \newenvironment{Schunk}{}{}%
\fi

\newcommand{\Sconcordance}[1]{%
  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined%
  \csname newcount\endcsname\pdfoutput\fi%
  \ifcase\pdfoutput\special{#1}%
  \else%
   \begingroup%
     \pdfcompresslevel=0%
     \immediate\pdfobj stream{#1}%
     \pdfcatalog{/SweaveConcordance \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}%
   \endgroup%
  \fi}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, need to set the options used in the R session:

```
<<customOptions,echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>=
    options(prompt   = "R> ",
            continue = "+    ")
@
```